# Let g(y)=$lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(xy)}{x^3}$. If g(1)=1, then for all y>0, find g(y)

Tags: calculus

Let $f:R \rightarrow R$ be a nonzero function such that $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(xy)}{x^3}$ exists for all y>0. Let g(y)=$lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(xy)}{x^3}$. If g(1)=1, then for all y>0, find g(y)

My approach is g(1)=$lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^3}=1$

We can write g(y)=$lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} y^3\frac{f(xy)}{{(xy)}^3}=y^3$

I wish to confirm if $g(y)=y^3$ is correct

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Thank you